# Wicked Fast Treeview Folders and Sub-Folders

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I found the code below somewhere on the web, and it is wicked fast at loading folders into a treeview.  My problem is that it only shows the top level folders, when I really want all folders and sub-folders.  Other examples are good but very slow in comparison to this code - and as I am an beginner coder, I don't know where to even start modifying it. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub LoadFolderTree(ByVal path As String)
    TreeView1.ImageIndex = 0
    Dim basenode As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode, volbl As String, drvltr As String = path
    If IO.Directory.Exists(path) Then
        If path.Length <= 3 Then
            volbl = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDriveInfo(path).VolumeLabel
            If Len(drvltr) = 3 Then drvltr = Mid(drvltr, 1, 2)
            basenode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(volbl & " (" & drvltr & ")")
        Else
            basenode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(path))
        End If
        basenode.Tag = path
        LoadDir(path, basenode)
    Else
        Throw New System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoadDir(ByVal DirPath As String, ByVal Node As Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Dir As String, DirName As String, Index As Integer
    If Node.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
        For Each Dir In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(DirPath)
            Index = Dir.LastIndexOf("\") : DirName = Dir.Substring(Index + 1, Dir.Length - Index - 1)
            If fncAddThisDir(DirName) Then
                Node.Nodes.Add(DirName)
                Node.LastNode.Tag = Dir
                Node.LastNode.ImageIndex = 2
                Node.LastNode.SelectedImageIndex = 2
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Function fncAddThisDir(ByVal dirname As String) As Boolean
    If Mid(LCase(dirname), 1, 7) = "program" Then dirname = "Program"
    Select Case LCase(dirname)
        Case ""
        Case "$avg", "$recycle.bin"
        Case "documents and settings", "windows", "system volume information"
        Case "config.msi", "boot", "msocache", "perflogs"
        Case "hp", "recovery", "swsetup", "program"
        Case "recycler", ".wd_tv"
        Case Else : Return True
    End Select
End Function
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Top of my head guess here, but think what you're looking for is recursively call LoadDir().  Probably want to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getdirectories?view=net-6.0

Comment: That said, once you start recursively searching the directory try, you're likely going to find stuff slows down quite a bit.  The fact it's only showing the top most folders is what makes this "WICKED" fast

Comment: Thanks Hursey for the prompt reply. Yep, you're absolutely right - I added a recursive call to LoadDir() and it all slowed down :(   Never mind, I'll just live with it. Thanks again.